# C# Multiple File Upload

Tags: c#

I have this working code to upload images into a MySQL table, works fine but I want to know what can I do to convert this one file upload to a multiple file upload. I know that I need a for but I dont know exactly where have to be.

```
protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    string contentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
    int alerta = Convert.ToInt32(this.alertatxt.Text);
    using (Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO foto(FileName, ContentType, Content, IdAlerta) VALUES (@FileName, @ContentType, @Content, @alerta)";
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", filename);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", bytes);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alerta", alerta);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Also if somebody can help me to verify the type of file is loaded into the input before uploaded, for example input only admits .png, .jpg, etc.

EDIT:

Im using .NET Framework 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through `FileUpload1.PostedFiles`, for verifying file extension make use of `path.GetExtension(fileName)` or you can restrict the file mime type on the iis from uploading.

Documentation:

`https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfiles.aspx`

EDIT:
For .Net framework below 4.5
upload the files through ajax and then on the server side

```
var fileCollection = Request.Files;
for (int i = 0; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
{
HttpPostedFile upload = fileCollection[i];
//Do your stuff
}
```

Client-Side:

```
function uploadFiles()
{
        var inputElement = document.getElementById("FileUpload1");
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200 && xhr.responseText) {
                alert("upload done!");
            }
            else {
                alert("upload failed!");
            }
        };
        xhr.open('POST', "WebForm1.aspx/upload");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
        xhr.send(inputElement.Files);
}
```

Html:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true"/>
    </div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="uploadFiles()" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: I get an error when I try to use PostedFiles, I think that its because Im working with 3.5 framework, let me add this to my question.

Comment: @F.Flores https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Comment: Server only works with 3.5 or below and I cant do something to change it.

Comment: @F.Flores i have updated my answer to include implementation for .net Framework below 3.5